# implementing getFilter() in custom adapter

Tags: android

Hi i am writing get filter method in my custom adapter. here is my getFilter() method in custom adapter

```
    package com.example.secureapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    private Context context;
    private int id;
    private ArrayList<Info> data;
    private ArrayList<Info> datavalues;
    private DataFilter filter;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<Info> objects) {
        this.context = context;
        this.id = textViewResourceId;
        this.data = (ArrayList<Info>) objects;
        datavalues = new ArrayList<Info>();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        Holder holder = new Holder();
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater i = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            view = i.inflate(id, parent, false);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
        }
        holder.name.setText(data.get(position).appName);
        holder.icon.setImageDrawable(data.get(position).icon);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    private class Holder {
        ImageView icon;
        TextView name;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {

        if (filter == null)
            filter = new DataFilter();
        return filter;
    }

    private class DataFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            data = (ArrayList<Info>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            FilterResults r = new FilterResults();

            if (datavalues == null) {

                synchronized (data) {
                    datavalues = new ArrayList<Info>(data);
                }

            }

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                synchronized (data) {
                    ArrayList<Info> list = new ArrayList<Info>(datavalues);
                    r.values = list;
                    r.count = list.size();
                }

            } else {

                ArrayList<Info> values = (ArrayList<Info>) datavalues;
                int count = values.size();
                ArrayList<Info> list = new ArrayList<Info>();
                String prefix = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

                    if (values.get(i).appName.toLowerCase().contains(prefix)) {
                        list.add(data.get(i));
                    }

                }

                r.values = list;
                r.count = list.size();

            }

            return r;

        }
    }
}
```

but i am getting this exception

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-03 14:36:41.011: E/AndroidRuntime(20938): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
08-03 14:36:41.011: E/AndroidRuntime(20938):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
08-03 14:36:41.011: E/AndroidRuntime(20938):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
08-03 14:36:41.011: E/AndroidRuntime(20938):    at com.example.secureapp.MyAdapter.getView(MyAdapter.java:46)
08-03 14:36:41.011: E/AndroidRuntime(20938):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1427)
08-03 14:36:41.011: E/AndroidRuntime(20938):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1273)
08-03 14:36:41.011: E/AndroidRuntime(20938):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1184)
08-03 14:36:41.011: E/AndroidRuntime(20938):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
08-03 14:36:41.011: E/AndroidRuntime(20938):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:563)
08-03 14:36:41.011: E/AndroidRuntime(20938):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:378)
08-03 14:36:41.011: E/AndroidRuntime(20938):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
08-03 14:36:41.011: E/AndroidRuntime(20938):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
08-03 14:36:41.011: E/AndroidRuntime(20938):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
08-03 14:36:41.011: E/AndroidRuntime(20938):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
08-03 14:36:41.011: E/AndroidRuntime(20938):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
08-03 14:36:41.011: E/AndroidRuntime(20938):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
08-03 14:36:41.011: E/AndroidRuntime(20938):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
08-03 14:36:41.011: E/AndroidRuntime(20938):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
08-03 14:36:41.011: E/AndroidRuntime(20938):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
08-03 14:36:41.011: E/AndroidRuntime(20938):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-03 14:36:41.011: E/AndroidRuntime(20938):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-03 14:36:41.011: E/AndroidRuntime(20938):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
08-03 14:36:41.011: E/AndroidRuntime(20938):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-03 14:36:41.011: E/AndroidRuntime(20938):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-03 14:36:41.011: E/AndroidRuntime(20938):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
08-03 14:36:41.011: E/AndroidRuntime(20938):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
08-03 14:36:41.011: E/AndroidRuntime(20938):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i am not getting it please help me!!

Answer (score 1):

Add Following `@Override

```
    public int getCount() {
          return data.size();
    }
```

below this

```
private ArrayList<Info> data;
```

use seperate list for filtering the data

```
private ArrayList<Info> datavalues ;
```

your getFilter function is returning the new instance of filter every-time instead of that create a single instance.

```
      @Override
      public Filter getFilter() {

        if (filter == null )
              filter  = new DataFilter();
        return filter ;
     }

       private class DataFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            data = (ArrayList<Info>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            FilterResults r = new FilterResults();

                    if (datavalues == null) {

                    synchronized (data) {
                        datavalues = new ArrayList<Info>(data);
                    }

                }

            if (constraint== null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                    synchronized (data) {
                        ArrayList<Info> list = new ArrayList<Info>(datavalues);
                        results.values = list;
                        results.count = list.size();
                    }

            }
            else {

               ArrayList<Info> values = (ArrayList<Info>)datavalues;
               int count = values.size();
               ArrayList<Info> list = new ArrayList<Info>();
               String prefix = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

            for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {

                if( values.get(i).appName.toLowerCase().contains(prefix) ) {
                             list.add(data.get(i));
                }

            }

             r.values = list;
             r.count  = list.size();

           }

            return r;

        }
```

Comment: problem inside your getView() function try to debug it after commenting the Holder code and share your inflate code.

Comment: My brain is fried from trying to resolve mine... can you help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524417/listview-is-blank-while-using-getfilter-function