# Android Filter ListView by BaseAdapter

Tags: android, android-adapter

i'm try to write simple filtering ListView by this below code. but that does not work correctly

in this code i'm using `ContactListStructure` class structure as:

```
public class ContactListStructure implements Serializable {
    public Long     id;
    public String   name;
    public String   mobile;
    public Bitmap   photo;
    public Boolean  checked;
    ...
}
```

and i'm fill this class as an ArrayList with phone contacts. after fill that i'm set this list into ListView without any problem,then i'm try to fillter this list by:

```
/* private ArrayList<ContactListStructure>  contact_item; */

contactsAdapter = new ContactsAdapter ( G.contact_item , ActivityContactList.this);
lstContent.setAdapter ( contactsAdapter );

search_contacts.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        contactsAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
});
```

**POST UPDATE**
`search_contacts` is an `EditText` and after type into that ListView dont filter and dont any change. my BaseAdapter :

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends BaseAdapter  implements Filterable {
    private Context mCtx=null;
    private ArrayList<ContactListStructure> mData=null;
    private ArrayList<ContactListStructure> arraylist;
    private List<ContactListStructure> worldpopulationlist = null;

    private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();
    static int i=0;
    public ContactsAdapter (ArrayList<ContactListStructure> contact_item, Context ctx) {
        mData=contact_item;
        mCtx=ctx;
        this.worldpopulationlist = contact_item;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ContactListStructure getItem(int position) {
            return worldpopulationlist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView==null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator=((Activity)mCtx).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView=inflator.inflate(R.layout.send_sms,null);

        }
        CheckBox  chk_name_mobile   = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.chk_name_mobile);
        ImageView photo             = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);

        String name=mData.get(position).name;
        chk_name_mobile.setText(name);
        if( mData.get(position).photo == null )
            photo.setImageDrawable( G.context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.user) );
        else
            photo.setImageBitmap(mData.get(position).photo);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter () {
        return mFilter;
    }

    private class ItemFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            String filterString = constraint.toString();
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            final ArrayList<ContactListStructure> list = mData;

            int count = list.size();
            final ArrayList<ContactListStructure> nlist = new ArrayList<ContactListStructure>(count);

            String filterableString ;

            for (ContactListStructure wp : worldpopulationlist)
            {
                if (wp.getName().contains(filterString))
                {
                    //Log.e ("wp: ", String.valueOf ( wp ) );
                    ContactListStructure item = new ContactListStructure();
                    item.id = wp.id;
                    item.name = wp.name;
                    item.mobile = wp.mobile;
                    item.photo = wp.photo;
                    nlist.add(item);
                }
            }

            results.values = nlist;
            results.count = nlist.size();

            return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            arraylist = (ArrayList<ContactListStructure>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE POST:**

after help in comments my `notifyDataSetChanged` not working. after type into edit text thats can be find but listview dont refresh.

Comment: i don't see any question mark here...

Comment: @pskink post updated with this Q mark `search_contacts` is an `EditText` and after type into that ListView dont filter and dont any change.

Comment: add some Log.d in performFiltering/publishResults, what do you see?

Comment: @pskink post updated with debug. end of quastion is updated

Comment: what's CharSequence constraint in publishResults?  "a"?

Comment: strange that results.values is null,  it should not be so,  why don't you use ArrayAdapter which already implements filtering?

Comment: @pskink i can not use ArrayAdapter. can you help me to change this adapter to ArrayAdapter?

Comment: @pskink POST UPDATE. problem resolved. my `notifyDataSetChanged` not working. after type into edit text thats can be find but listview dont refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following this question here: [ListView is blank while using getFilter function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20524417/listview-is-blank-while-using-getfilter-function)

It was able to filter based on a choice from the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to add the data returned from result to your `mData` :

```
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        arraylist = (ArrayList<ContactListStructure>) results.values;
        mData.clear();
        for(int i = 0, i < arraylist.size(); i++)
           mData.add(arraylist.get(i));
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm updated your pasted code to currect code.thanks. now i get this error sometimes: `The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.`

Comment: @andbee Try to debug your code and see if the error occureed when filtering. There is a possibility the error is happened because other code. Make sure you only call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the UI Thread