# Android for notifyDataSetChanged() get IllegalStateException error

Tags: android, android-adapter

in this BaseAdapter i want to refresh list view by filtering that. after type into EditText i get `IllegalStateException` error for `notifyDataSetChanged();` into Adapter.

Logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.
```

My code to filtering listView in activity:

```
search_contacts.addTextChangedListener ( new TextWatcher () {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged (Editable arg0) {
        final String text = search_contacts.getText ().toString ().toLowerCase ( Locale.getDefault () );
        contactsAdapter.filter ( text );
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence arg0, int arg1,int arg2, int arg3) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged (CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {
    }
});
```

my BaseAdapter:

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {
    private Context mCtx=null;
    private ArrayList<ContactListStructure> mData=null;
    private ArrayList<ContactListStructure> arraylist;
    private List<ContactListStructure> worldpopulationlist = null;
    //private ItemFilter mFilter = new ItemFilter();
    static int i=0;
    public ContactsAdapter (ArrayList<ContactListStructure> contact_item, Context ctx)    {
        mData=contact_item;
        mCtx=ctx;
        this.worldpopulationlist = contact_item;
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<ContactListStructure>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(worldpopulationlist);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return worldpopulationlist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ContactListStructure getItem(int position) {
            return worldpopulationlist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        ImageView photo;
        CheckBox  chk_name_mobile;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        if(convertView==null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)mCtx).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.send_sms, null);

            holder.chk_name_mobile   = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chk_name_mobile);
            holder.photo             = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        String name=mData.get(position).name;
        holder.chk_name_mobile.setText(name);
        if( mData.get(position).photo == null )
            holder.photo.setImageDrawable( G.context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.user) );
        else
            holder.photo.setImageBitmap(mData.get(position).photo);
        return convertView;
    }

    public void filter(String charText) {
        worldpopulationlist.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            worldpopulationlist.addAll(arraylist);
        }
        else
        {
            for (ContactListStructure wp : worldpopulationlist)
            {
                if (wp.getName ().contains(wp.name))
                {
                    ContactListStructure item = new ContactListStructure();
                    item.id = wp.id;
                    item.name = wp.name;
                    item.mobile = wp.mobile;
                    item.photo = wp.photo;
                    arraylist.add(item);

                }
                Log.e ( "wp.name: ", wp.name );
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should implement `Filterable` in your adapter and `override` its methods

Comment: @BlazeTama thanks. can you help me in in this link: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272630/android-filter-listview-by-baseadapter` thats BaseAdapter and implement Filterable, but list veiw doesnt refresh

Comment: Is this error occuring on every time or just on when you type fast?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you edit the content twice without call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.
in the line below you delete everything from the adapter without notify.

```
worldpopulationlist.clear();
```